# print specific fields from toString()

Tags: java, arrays, string, casting, arraylist

Im using the following code to get data from JPA class

```
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("abc");
        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

    classList.add("pack.Person");

    for (Object classOjc : classList) {

        String className = classOjc.toString();

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM " + className + " p");

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        List resultList = query.getResultList();

        System.out.println(resultList.size());

        for (Object result : resultList) {

            System.out.println(result.toString());
        }
    }
}



Person [firstName=firstName 1, lastName=lastName 1, bigDecimal=0, myDate=Wed Sep 16 06:42:18 IST 1998], 
Person [firstName=firstName 2, lastName=lastName 2, bigDecimal=0, myDate=Sun May 19 13:12:51 IDT 1957], 
Person [firstName=firstName 3, lastName=lastName 3, bigDecimal=0, myDate=Fri Jun 03 05:09:20 IDT 1949],
```

the class is

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + 
             "]";


....
```

my question is assume that the override result is like  following (give all the attribute and class name),
there is a way

Since I override the toString() of the person class the print is like follows but my question
is there is a way to print for example just the field names or just the values(assume that I cannot change the to string and it should be the same for every class)
the problem is that i can get **any class** so I can cast the result to person for instance

Comment: If you don't know what the incoming class is and you don't want to cast then the only recourse is reflection.

Comment: What are you trying to ask?  The sentence that starts "My question is..." never seems to make it to a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reflectively `toString` a given `Class` without knowing its type.

Simply loop over it's declared fields and get their values:

```
public static String myMagicToString(final Object in) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append(in.getClass().getSimpleName()).
            append(" [");
    for (final Field field : in.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        stringBuilder.append(field.getName()).
                append("=").
                append(field.get(in)).
                append(",");
    }
    stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
    stringBuilder.append("]");
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

This example prints the same format as you describe, but you just need to amend string concatenation and you can easily change the format.

Comment: HI Boris,when i use your code i get the class metadata like Person [id=0,firstName=null,lastName=null,double1=0.0] but I want to match the value from the result the i get from the query to the field value ,how can i do that?

Comment: I don't userstand what you mean. If you want to filter values on some criteria then you can pass in a callback, such a [Predicate](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html), and check whether the field's name matches the criteria or not.

Comment: I need to take the result string and create from it object that contain the entity name and list of respective fields and values,so how can i take it from the result string for example if from the third list i want to print just the lastName=lastName 3 how should i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add multiple toString methods  as per your need. Or write a single method with attributes list that you want to print.

Comment: Can you please provide an example how to print multiple toString and how to call to it within the for statement .Thanks